# SystemOutOfMemory Exception When Loading .JPG's

Tags: c#

I am trying to put the entire collection of images in a user's Pictures folder into an `ObservableCollection` (Images). If I get only .png's it works fine, but if I also try to get .jpg's it throws a `SystemOutOfMemory` exception. I am using the following code:

```
String picturesPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(picturesPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

foreach (String file in files)
{
    ImageInfo newImage = new ImageInfo() { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Path = file };    //Id and Path are properties of newImage, defined by the ImageInfo class
    if (file.EndsWith(".png") || file.EndsWith(".jpg")) Images.Add(newImage);
}
```

EDIT: I am using the following code to add the images to a `StackPanel`. (`RibbonButton` is a custom component).

```
foreach (ImageInfo image in startup.Images)
        {
            Image newImage = new Image();
            newImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(image.Path, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            RibbonButton newRibbonButton = new RibbonButton();
            RibbonButton.SetCornerRadius(newRibbonButton, new CornerRadius(0));
            SolidColorBrush brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DarkGray);
            RibbonButton.SetIsPressedBackground(newRibbonButton, brush);
            newRibbonButton.Content = newImage;
            newRibbonButton.ToolTip = image.Path;
            newRibbonButton.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
            newRibbonButton.Margin = new Thickness(5);
            newRibbonButton.Width = 100;
            newRibbonButton.Height = 60;
            imagesListStackPanel.Children.Add(newRibbonButton);
        }
```

EDIT: The `OnPropertyChanged` handler:

```
#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
#endregion
#region OnPropertyChanged
protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
#endregion OnPropertyChanged
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Thanks

Comment: how many files are you opening?

Comment: @DLeh It varies. I have tried limiting it to just one or two, but it still crashes.

Comment: Do you load the image data itself? If so, how do you do it?

Comment: @Traubenfuchs All I'm loading is the file path.

Comment: Just to make sure - instead of adding to Images, try adding the ImageInfo to a list and do nothing with it. This way you will see if its the Imageinfo or that it's the binding that takes your memory

Comment: Is ImageInfo a class made by your own? Can you show us the ctr? (image loading part)

Comment: Do you also get the exception if the directory contains the one single jpg?

Comment: @YoryeNathan Yes I do.

Comment: On what line is the exception thrown?

Comment: @YoryeNathan It doesn't give it on a line. It just pops up a dialog.

Comment: I cannot see that you are loading the image anywhere - where do you get the exception?

Comment: I wonder what's happening in OnPropertyChanged (;

Comment: I wonder what's happening in the `ObservableCollection` events handlers in general.

Comment: @Drowin And what does the stacktrace show?

Comment: @Traubenfuchs I have added the `OnPropertyChanged` handler.

Comment: It seems like you do load the images after all. Is the Exception thrown if you explicitly call the new BitmapImage(...) constructor on the path of the offending .jpg that is causing the exception?

Comment: @YoryeNathan It simply says `The function evaluation was disabled because of an out of memory exception.`

Comment: @Traubenfuchs No it does not.

Comment: What size is the jpg?

Comment: @YoryeNathan It ranges from 7KB to 8MB.

Answer (score 4):

`Directory.GetFiles` loads all file names into memory. You can use `EnumerateFiles` if you don't need all of them:

```
foreach(var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(picturesPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

Or via `LINQ` you can make it more cleaner:

```
var images = Directory.EnumerateFiles(picturesPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        .Where(f => Path.GetExtension(f) == ".png" || Path.GetExtension(f) == ".jpg")
        .Select(file => new ImageInfo() 
                        { 
                           Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),  
                           Path = file 
                        });

foreach(var img in images)
{
   Images.Add(img);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I still get the exception.

Comment: this should definitely reduce the memory usage.. how many files are you loading?

Comment: I had put that before you added the `LINQ`. I tried the `LINQ`, but I'm not very familiar at all with it, and it doesn't like the `.ToArray()`. It says `Cannot implicitly convert type 'Indol.Core.ImageInfo[]' to 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<Indol.Core.ImageInfo>`

Comment: @Drowin I thought you have an array, anyway I edited my answer.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. I tried that, but it still uses about 1.75 GB of memory and throws the exception.

Comment: well I think either you have too many files or the error is completely irrevelant the code you have shown us.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Selmen22's solution, you can restructure your logic to avoid loading images and creating instances of `ImageInfo` that you're not interested in.

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(picturesPath, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
{
    if (file.EndsWith(".png") || file.EndsWith(".jpg"))
    {
        ImageInfo newImage = new ImageInfo() { Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Path = file };
        Images.Add(newImage);
    }
}
```